# How do I capture console output from a remote NSight session?

Tags: cuda, console, remote-debugging, nvidia, nsight

I have a set of CUDA apps that both write to the console via `cout`. I have a host machine with VS and NSight plug-in and a target machine with NSight service. However, when I execute the console app, it actually runs on the target machine (literally pops up a console).

So here's the question: how can I get the console to show up on the host and only the GPU stuff to execute on the target? Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it is currently not possible. The application on the target is executed by the Nsight Monitor process but Nsight Monitor currently does not forward the output back to host.
Currently your only option is to take care of it your self by capturing the output of your application on the target and somehow display it on the host.
If this feature is important to you i suggest you file a feature request via your Nvidia developer account.

Comment: It's not strictly speaking NVIDIA's concern. I was thinking maybe VS has something for this. (Unrelated to Remote Debugging, that is.)

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk as far as i can tell when doing CUDA debugging VS is merely a frontend for Nsight, there is no connection between VS and the code running on the target machine, even when target and host are the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

The CUDA application completely runs on the target machine, so the console or UI for the application will be seen on the target machine only.  You can set breakpoints in the GPU code in the VS side (your host machine), and it should break there.
If you feel the application quits too quickly and is not launching the kernels as expected (and you are not hitting the breakpoints), it may be that you have not deployed all the required DLLs on the target machine (e.g. CUDART).

Comment: I understand all that. Yet my problem remains.